# [MariaDB 10.3 -> MariaDB 10.6][InnoDB] Duplicate entry '...' for key 'unique_index'

Tags: mariadb, innodb

Recently we upgraded mariadb from 10.3 to 10.6 and we are facing a weird problem.
Although there is a unique key on 3 columns (`table_hash`,`table_id`,`meta_key`) there are multiple records with same data.
It didn't happen when we were on mariadb 10.3.

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ordini_meta` (
  `meta_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `table_hash` bigint(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `table_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `meta_key` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `ordini_meta`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`table_hash`,`table_id`,`meta_key`),
  ADD KEY `table_hash` (`table_hash`),
  ADD KEY `table_id` (`table_id`),
  ADD KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`);

ALTER TABLE `ordini_meta`
  MODIFY `meta_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**Example of duplicates**:

[image]

Rows in the table are managed with PHP and the query used is:

```
INSERT INTO ordini_meta (table_hash,table_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES (%d,%d,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_id=LAST_INSERT_ID(meta_id), meta_value=%s"
```

**SHOW VARIABLES 10.6(now):**
[paste bin](https://pastebin.com/bhHYgMSb)

**SHOW VARIABLES 10.3(before upgrade):**
[paste bin](https://pastebin.com/hpbMXCPi)

We really don't understand why it happens.
Any help is really appreciated.

### **UPDATE 2023-06-07**

It seems problem has been solved after following tuning.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 32
innodb_write_io_threads = 4
innodb_read_io_threads = 4
thread_pool_size = 8
table_open_cache_instances = 64
table_open_cache = 2048
table_definition_cache = 2048
join_buffer_size = 2MB
```

Comment: Maybe  [unique_checks](https://mariadb.com/docs/server/sql/features/constraints/enterprise-server/unique/) on the old server was disabled and automatically enabled after upgrade. By the way the point of unique constraint is to have unique values

Comment: Thanks @ErgestBasha. I saved 10.3 variables too before upgrade, I added it to the post.
unique_checks is ON in both.

Comment: Looks like a [bug that should be reported](https://jira.mariadb.org/). Can you tell by the rows if they existing in 10.3 before the upgrade? Was this an inplace upgrade? Was the unique key added in 10.3 or after the 10.6 upgrade? Can you include more of the mariadb log? If the index existed in 10.3 it might be a corrupted index, and if so, recommend dropping the index and re-creating it with "ALTER IGNORE" or some other mechanism of resolving the duplicates correctly. If there are duplicates on a 10.6+ created index please do a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/).

Comment: thanks @danblack DB structure is the same that was in 10.3, unique key was already there before upgrade.
In 10.3 there weren't any duplicate rows.
We restored the database from a backup(mysqldump) and everyday we need to delete duplicate rows.
We also tried to re-create index many times.
I suppose I just need to create a bug report.

Comment: Thanks . Appoligies for the difficulties.

Comment: It seems the problem has been solved after the tuning i posted above in my update

Comment: I'm glad you're not seeing it but I suspect you've tuned away the likelihood of seeing it. `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is deprecated too.

Comment: @danblack I don't really know what the tuning caused but we don't have any duplicate anymore. You are right, I saw innodb_buffer_pool_instances is deprecated in the log, after added it.